# Google Maps custom marker icon not appearing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I created an own map on Google Maps which uses custom marker icons. These icons appear fine when I am logged in with my Google Account ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/457fM.jpg)). However, they do not appear when I [share the map](https://maps.google.de/maps/ms?msid=207304257835995764264.0004d50bd479c35bfc590&msa=0&ll=49.008995,8.401022&spn=0.045547,0.077162&iwloc=0004d50bda79516f0fd31) to public.

Can anyone please explain me why this happens?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those icons are not publicly available.  Make them publicly available or link to ones that are. From your KML:

[style3](https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/0/AAB5jRBjSQzFRwC_3prIMxcIAjUi0gYtLn-0yv5-Z0t50Q/10/8902804/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/Givebox.png/mHDsU8NZ4bX5F7DdqF-n6LRhWOZEf5c_L4z9SjgpnpU?size=32bf&prep_size=1024x768)

[style4](https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/0/AAD6t9o6b1MN8DD6lFbHPBhi4_9_KcLOi6MoWC66RsVvgA/10/8902804/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/Buecherschrank.png/PjQg39_walneLADs9FjOPe2ZR5AbiOCftvRpMF--uKU?size=32bf&prep_size=800x600)

[style7](https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/0/AAAj0BHi89UqEbl82Xekwv_MSGSyK8snTmeq7fWiMIsJlg/10/8902804/png/1024x768/2/1360155600/0/2/Alnatura.png/P3AKHe_CI1dGYRcGGXlOaq7LYfdqQRAMDTBDV5l2FQ0)

[style2](https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/0/AAD6t9o6b1MN8DD6lFbHPBhi4_9_KcLOi6MoWC66RsVvgA/10/8902804/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/Buecherschrank.png/PjQg39_walneLADs9FjOPe2ZR5AbiOCftvRpMF--uKU?size=32bf&prep_size=1024x768)

[style1](https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/0/AACa9wJPOnX92RX9ST6xUzIwLWObwjc6NPO3ZfMfI3inwQ/10/8902804/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/Alnatura.png/wdnr5qVd6wOSkvHXVaLrwKo06hHXGMXlgmFftuXiVMc?size=1024x768&size_mode=2)

[style8](https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/0/AAB5jRBjSQzFRwC_3prIMxcIAjUi0gYtLn-0yv5-Z0t50Q/10/8902804/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/Givebox.png/mHDsU8NZ4bX5F7DdqF-n6LRhWOZEf5c_L4z9SjgpnpU?size=32bf&prep_size=1024x768)

[style5](https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/0/AAAVwyBw8iR3pXIqh68ZrU8geV0GpCDKLe1a92SK4n912g/10/8902804/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/Fuellhorn.png/hNUYFJzUUn4XplF6IaGdlQ_OxOLEQAfgK-2OvL_etWk?size=32bf&prep_size=1024x768)

[style6](https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/0/AACQ6mOgHhqeOl1y70CTb3reXMu0isr5ULMJbFGhsWqxBw/10/8902804/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/Weltladen.png/A8U6UX7yHxohcoh_Xncs9fx5GaJnaefo6-PRLWHcqLU?size=32bf&prep_size=1024x768)

Comment: Thank you! How stupid that I did not pay attention to the problem of public availability when using Dropbox links. It is working now.